# How to get a list of interpolated values at fixed timesteps from a time sorted list without constant timesteps

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a long file containing temperature data and I want to align the temperatures by interpolation to fixed time steps (5 minutes spacing).

```
17.06.2023 16:11:59 : tfa 27.2
17.06.2023 16:19:47 : tfa 27.4
17.06.2023 16:27:36 : tfa 28.2
17.06.2023 16:35:50 : tfa 28.7
17.06.2023 16:42:52 : tfa 28.1
```

As a start the regular times for the interpolation would be like: `times = pd.date_range(beginTime, endTime, freq='5min')`

I tried `np.interp` but I'm stuck how to deal with the 2 time frames.

The result should be the a list or a dataframe with interpolated values at the 5 minutes timesteps.
I saw multiple questions here but either the proposed solution was long code or, only one value was interpolated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to transform your dates to numbers before using `np.interp`

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, and has fields `time` and `temp`, then

```py
dref=datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,0,0,0) # it doesn't really matter, we just need a reference date. But we don't really care about absolute value of dates here. So, it could be any date. Or the 1st one of your dataset, or anything

temp5m = np.interp((times-dref).total_seconds(), (df.time-dref).dt.total_seconds(), df.temp)
#temp5m is the temperatures at all times in `times`
```

[mre]

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# An example dataframe
realTimes = datetime.datetime(2023,6,17,16,19,12)+np.random.randint(100,600,15).cumsum()*datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
temps = np.random.uniform(10,40,(15,))
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':realTimes, 'temp':temps})

# Your 5 min sampling
times = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2023,6,17,16,20,0), datetime.datetime(2023,6,17,17,0,0), freq='5min')

# Interpolation
dref=datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,0,0,0) # any date
temp5m = np.interp((times-dref).total_seconds(), (df.time-dref).dt.total_seconds(), df.temp)
newDf = pd.DataFrame({'time':times, 'temp':temp5m})
```

Example result

```
#df (original data)
                  time       temp
0  2023-06-17 16:26:33  14.262191
1  2023-06-17 16:30:24  20.912985
2  2023-06-17 16:39:20  22.200749
3  2023-06-17 16:44:36  21.480998
4  2023-06-17 16:52:25  27.560285
5  2023-06-17 16:54:42  30.539957
6  2023-06-17 17:01:22  37.876850
7  2023-06-17 17:05:34  32.759001
8  2023-06-17 17:14:01  35.002006
9  2023-06-17 17:20:01  29.407395
10 2023-06-17 17:25:40  19.016240
11 2023-06-17 17:30:45  12.738010
12 2023-06-17 17:32:26  11.023019
13 2023-06-17 17:34:17  19.283733
14 2023-06-17 17:40:28  34.920434

# newDf
                 time       temp
0 2023-06-17 16:20:00  14.262191
1 2023-06-17 16:25:00  14.262191
2 2023-06-17 16:30:00  20.221994
3 2023-06-17 16:35:00  21.576087
4 2023-06-17 16:40:00  22.109641
5 2023-06-17 16:45:00  21.792091
6 2023-06-17 16:50:00  25.680761
7 2023-06-17 16:55:00  30.870118
8 2023-06-17 17:00:00  36.372787
```

Note the 2 first lines, because they are before the 1st actual data, they are just set equal to first data. So, be sure, if you don't want that, to have your 5m timestamps inside the scope of your real data.

Note 2 : I am pretty sure there are some ways to do that with `resample`.
For example, but that is not optimal at all
`df.resample('1s').interpolate().resample('300s').nearest()`
(with df index being the time)

Note 3 : Be careful with interpolation ; it smoothes the extrema. That may be not wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. It works great for me.

Comment: How would I delete the sequence numbers in the resulting newDf? I need the first column to be a datetime.

Comment: Oh, you mean the index. So what you want is to build a dataframe whose index is time, and whose unique column is temperature. Replace the line `newDf = ...` by `newDf = pd.DataFrame({'temp':temp5m}, index=times)`

Comment: Great and easy, that was the final fix for my program.